# trouble running app in real device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, device

for the last month i have try to finish an app for mi android cel, when i finally finish i run using the virtual device and it work like i charm, how ever when i try to run using a real device the app starts but then show a black screen this is the first app y try using a real device and have no idea the reason for why in virtual device it works and not in a real device can anyone tell where i can find a reason for since the logcat in eclipse is not explicit of why it wont work.

this is the logcat when it wont works:

```
10-12 13:39:07.578: D/dalvikvm(9995): Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-12 13:39:07.593: I/dalvikvm(9995): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...
10-12 13:39:08.188: D/dalvikvm(9995): GC_CONCURRENT freed 138K, 3% free 9507K/9735K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-12 13:39:08.488: D/AndroidRuntime(9995): Shutting down VM
10-12 13:39:08.488: W/dalvikvm(9995): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c671f8)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "350,32"
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:332)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at com.example.mezcla2.MainActivity$9.hoja1_Tb1(MainActivity.java:484)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at com.example.mezcla2.MainActivity$9.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:444)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:882)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:848)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4518)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-12 13:39:08.498: E/AndroidRuntime(9995):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "350,32"

Comment: Have you looked at the exception itself and tried to rectify the situation? Or just throw a giant logcat at us without trying yourself? If you have tried, *what* have you tried?

Comment: i tried to find from the logcat the exceptions but i don understan the logcat for instance the part: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "350,32" in my code i don have anywere "350,32"

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are not allowing for the number formatting of different locales.

For example, in the UK a number would be written as 350.32 but in Spain it would be 350,32

Trying to use a specific number format when it is not supported by the locale would throw the exception you are experiencing.

Your device is likely using a locale that is not supported for the number you have used but your emulator is not.

The error is being thrown in an anonymous inner class (hoja1_Tb1) in your MainActivity. Line 484

***EDIT:***

> **Logcat Analysis:**
>
> Looking back through the logcat for code that is in your classes and
>   not in a built in class.
>
> **com.example.mezcla2.MainActivity$9.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:444)**
>
> then
>
> **com.example.mezcla2.MainActivity$9.hoja1_Tb1(MainActivity.java:484)**
>
> Then the code attempts to convert "something" to a Double.

This tells us that you have an inner class calling "onItemSelected" which then calls "hoja1_Tb1" at line 484

Then you get the actual error. Something at this location is trying to use a number that is not a valid number for the locale you are using.

The best thing you can do is learn how to read and interpret logcat. You have no hope of producing anything in code if you cannot find where you are going wrong.

Comment: i tried to find from the logcat the exceptions but i don understan the logcat for instance the part: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "350,32" in my code i don have anywere "350,32 so this response wont help at all

Comment: In the class i told you, on the line number i told you, for the reason I told you your code throwing an error by trying to use that number. You don't have to have the number in your code. This is a very simple error and is the answer to your question. There is no easier way to explain it and it not possible for us to guess what it is that is wrong with your code as you have only posted a logcat. Perhaps you need to post a new question that asks why your code is throwing the error but there is nothing left of this question to answer.

Comment: Logcat has told you exactly what the problem is. I have told you the most likely reason that problem is occurring. I have edited my answer to give you more information on reading logcat. It is now up to you. Apply the information you have been given or ask a new question and post the code that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must make sure that your physical device(phone) is enabled for the running android apps in areal device.
steps:-

1. Go to your phone and go to settings.
2. Instead of general settings Go to ALL.
3. Touch Developers option while your device is connected to the computer.
4. Then Enable USB debugging.
5. Then run the app. again then you will see your device.